# Insert image inside a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In a brief, user are able to select an image from their device gallery, and upon submit that images is display on screen to the output with the id "file". When a user select another picture, another one display right next to it until the counter reaches 3.

I would like to specify specifically where the two other images will be placed. And hence, I was thinking image1 would be associated with

```
<br><output id="list"></output>,
image 2 <br><output id="list2"></output>, etc
```

I have tried to adjust the code, but my attempt have failed.
Below is the code I've found that allows you to select a picture from your device and outputs on screen, but my problem is that i want to output the two other pictures in a different id.

http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/13/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to edit document.getElementById('list2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
<br>
<output id="img1"></output>
<br>
<output id="img2"></output>
<br>
<output id="img3"></output>
<br>
<output id="img4"></output>
```

then

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
    if (this.files.length > 4) {
        alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    var files = this.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }
        (function(i){
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('img' + (i + 1)).appendChild(span);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        })(i);
    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7h81p0mp/)

Comment: the images don't seem to appear at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the two other pictures in a different id, you also need to edit the JavaScript that identifies those HTML elements.

For example

```
document.getElementById('list2').insertBefore(span, null);
```

or

```
 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener
```

you can add new HTML elements for the outputs to the main HTML page

```
 <output id="list2"></output>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt response. Ive tried the following: http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/15/ but it doesn't seem to be working properly. it seems that now i have to select 3 images per id, where I want to limit to 1 image per id